# How Do I Set Up A Private Nuget Package Registry with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2019, github-package-registry

I am attempting to make available a .NET Framework v4.5.2 package in Visual Studio 2019, via NuGet Package Manager, and sourced from Github's private NuGet package registry system.

### Important Stuff I'm Using:

- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Github Actions
- Github
- Github Package Registry (GPR)
- Visual Studio 2019/NuGet Package Manager

### What Is My Goal?

The whole lifecycle looks a bit like this:

1. My project's repo has a CI job (Github brand) to `msbuild` & publish `nupkg`. It wraps everything up and deploys it to https://nuget.pkg.github.com/< my-private-org >.
2. In Visual Studio 2019, with a given project cracked open, a user should be able to reference https://nuget.pkg.github.com/< my-private-org > as a custom NuGet feed, and declare "My Project" as a dependency.

### What Works, What Doesn't?

- GitHub **successfully publishes** my package--I can see it when I visit https://github.com/my-private-organization?tab=packages.
- However, I **cannot** make Visual Studio 2019 support my private NuGet registry. When I attempt to access it, I get the error:

```
[Private] Failed to retrieve metadata from source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<my-private-organization>/query?q=&skip=0&take=26&prerelease=true&supportedFramework=.NETFramework,Version=v4.7&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

When I attempt to run the same query (`GET https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<my-private-organization>/query?q=&skip=0&take=26&prerelease=true&supportedFramework=.NETFramework,Version=v4.7&semVerLevel=2.0.0'`) in the browser, I am prompted with a modal to enter my GitHub credentials, but after entering them, I am met with the same 401, but a different error message:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    { 
      "code" : "Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the following scopes",
      "message":" ['read:packages'], but your token has only been granted the: [''] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: https://github.com/settings/tokens."
    }
  ]
}
```

I definitely have a `GITHUB_TOKEN` with `read:package` perms--I used it to generate the package in the first place in my CI job.

### I am suspicious that...

I need to pass my `read:package` credentialed `GITHUB_TOKEN` as extra auth-credentials, but I don't know if/how I can configure that in `nuget.config`. Which leads us to...

### What is my configuration?

I read that I need to parameterize my `%APPDATA%/NuGet/nuget.config` with some extra credential information, which I got from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials.  I can confirm that I'm updating the correct `nuget.config` file--I've been able to change package stream names in Visual Studio with the file I'm touching.  It now looks a bit like:

```xml
<!-- file: nuget.config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Private" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/###############/index.json" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Private>
        <add key="Username" value="###############" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="*******************" />
        <!-- Could I perhaps need to introduce my Github Access Token here? -->
    </Private>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The username and password specified in `packageSourceCredentials` are the same I used in the manual `GET` query done in the browser (which failed in a 401).

All thoughts are welcome, even "Nobody Does A".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to consume the nuget from Github package feed, you have to use GitHub personal access token, not your Github username and password.

Read the official doc on GitHub:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token

Use this guide to create personal access token:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Eriawan, respectfully could you explain the difference between a personal access token and a github token?  Thanks for the answer

Comment: My mistake, I should clarify "should not use userid + password". I'll update my answer.

Comment: Incredible. This indeed fixed the issue @Erianwan.  Thank you, again! I could have sworn I had already tried this.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯